# DIscord.js v13 i have a spam detector code which doesn't do it's work

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My discord.js v13 project on a spam detector doesn't work properly. It doesn't send any problem in the terminal but doesn't delete the message:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'messageCreate',
  run: async (client, message) => {
    const spamTracker = new Map();
    if (spamTracker.has(author.id)) {
      const data = spamTracker.get(author.id);
      const timeDifference = message.createdTimestamp - data.lastMessageTimestamp;
      if (timeDifference < 2000 && data.messageCount > 4) {
        console.log('done');
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send(`${author}, please refrain from spamming.`);
      }
      data.messageCount++;
      data.lastMessageTimestamp = message.createdTimestamp;
      spamTracker.set(author.id, data);
    } else {
      spamTracker.set(author.id, {
        messageCount: 1,
        lastMessageTimestamp: message.createdTimestamp,
      });
    }
    if (content.length > MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
      message.delete().then(() => {
        message.reply('Attention! You have exceeded the maximum allowed message length.');
      });
    }
  },
};
```

I tried to change `run` to `excute` but that doesn't work either. I think the problem is in the `spamtracker` map but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You're defining `spamTracker` inside of the event. This means it gets reassigned (restarts) on each message. Define `spamTracker` at the very top

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in this code:

1. The `author` variable is not defined. To access the author of the message, you need to use `message.author`.
2. The `content` variable is not defined. To access the content of the message, you need to use `message.content`.
3. The `MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH` constant is not defined. You need to define this constant with the maximum allowed message length.
4. The `run` function should be changed to `execute` if that's the desired name, but make sure to update the code accordingly.

Here's an updated code with the fixes

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'messageCreate',
  execute: async (client, message) => {
    const spamTracker = new Map();
    const author = message.author;
    const content = message.content;
    const MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 200;

    if (spamTracker.has(author.id)) {
      const data = spamTracker.get(author.id);
      const timeDifference = message.createdTimestamp - data.lastMessageTimestamp;
      if (timeDifference < 2000 && data.messageCount > 4) {
        console.log('done');
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send(`${author}, please refrain from spamming.`);
      }
      data.messageCount++;
      data.lastMessageTimestamp = message.createdTimestamp;
      spamTracker.set(author.id, data);
    } else {
      spamTracker.set(author.id, {
        messageCount: 1,
        lastMessageTimestamp: message.createdTimestamp,
      });
    }

    if (content.length > MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
      message.delete().then(() => {
        message.reply('Attention! You have exceeded the maximum allowed message length.');
      });
    }
  },
};
```